# Using Azure Service Bus (pub/sub) with Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, azureservicebus

I'd like to use a cloud based pub/sub implementation on Windows Phone 8. I'm trying to connect two+ phones together (think words with friends style turn based) and I know Azure can do this, but not all the DLLs are available on Windows phone (7/8). Does anyone have good reference material for pulling off pub/sub on a Windows phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For broadcasting/push-type notifications, please look at SignalR (http://signalr.net/). Microsoft is making that part of the ASP.NET platform: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034

It has some real nice functionality like gracefully, falling back on multiple mechanisms if advanced things like WebSockets are not supported by the server/client.  This is an ideal solution and super scalable, since it is server based and very light on the client.